# Как манипулировать объектом в другом классе

Tags: java

Есть объект в классе `Main`, созданный на основе класса

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            FormMenu windowMenu = new FormMenu(); // Вот он
        }                        
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Игра была успешно завершина!", "Информация",1); 
             System.exit(0);
        }                                               
    }
}
```

Я хочу манипулировать им в другом классе, но просто не знаю как его передать туда. Вот второй класс, куда надо передать.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PanelMenu extends JPanel
{

    public PanelMenu()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Играть");
        button1.setBounds(275,170,250,40);
        add(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                FormSpace windowSpace = new FormSpace();
                // Вот тут я хочу его просто скрыть 
                windowsMenu.setVisible(false); // Но его надо передать
            }
        });

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Настройки");
        button2.setBounds(275,220,250,40);
        add(button2);

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
              String hut = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Укажите цвет подарка (blue,orange,green)");
            }
        });

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Выход");
        button3.setBounds(275,270,250,40);
        add(button3);

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Игра была успешно завершина!", "Информация",1);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(200, 150, 400, 180);
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за подсказку или чтиву

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, создай какой-нибудь класс MenuManager, который управляет твоими меню. Внутри него создашь экземпляры классов обоих менюшек. А экземпляр самого MenuManager создай в том классе, котором тебе надо ( например в Main ) и у него ты будешь вызывать методы ( например showPanelMenu() ).

Comment: Спасибо большое , буду пробовать